# How determine cookie expiration date in java servlet?

Tags: servlets, cookies

Java servlet API returns a [cookie](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) which has `getMaxAge` method. It return how long cookie exists, but does not tell when it will be removed in browser.

Is it possible to calculate expiration date via servlet API?

Comment: "now" + maxAge, no?? (beware to the -1 case)

Comment: First of all - browser and sever time may be different, second - could you please proove that `getMaxAge` is counted from `now`? I does not see this in cookie javadoc. :(

Comment: According to http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073096/don-t-trust-cookie-setmaxage.html, `setMaxAge()` takes the server time add s the age and use that for the expiration date. So I think we can assume the `getMaxAge` does the reverse (computed from the cookie expiration date). (but maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, it's easy to test)

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is something directly available to calculate expiration date of cookie.
But best bet will be while setting cookie,you can store the timestamp somewhere and by using that and the `getMaxAge()`,you can calculate when it is going to expire.